# Update a variable from global.R in shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, scope

I want to update the dataframe DF_SERIE created in the global.R file so that it will still be accessible everywhere in the shiny app.But after I updated it (bind_rows data from an upload form) the new value is only accessible in the upload_tab_server.R page.
How can I make it global ?

The app.R file

```
app <- shinyAppDir("App", options = list(launch.browser = TRUE))
```

The global.R file

```
# Load data
DF_REF_S <- read_delim("file_s.csv")

# Import calculation function
source("fonctions/calculs.R")

DF_SERIE <- calculSerie(DF_REF_S)
```

The server.R file

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  uploadTabServer("upload", output, input, session)
  serieTabServer("serie_display", output, input, session)
  
}
```

The upload_tab_server.R file

```
uploadTabServer <- function(id, output, input, session){
  
  # retrieve data from upload page
  result_input2 <- reactive({

    DF_UPLOAD <- bind_rows(purrr::map(input$files$datapath, ~ read.csv2(.)))
    
    # Add rows to the existing dataframe
    DF_SERIE <- bind_rows(DF_SERIE, DF_UPLOAD)
    
    source("fonctions/calculs.R")
    DF_SERIE <- calculSerie(DF_REF_S)
    
    return(DF_SERIE)
   
  })
  
}
```

Comment: One option would to use `reactiveVal` or `reactiveValues`.